# How do I detect when a removable disk is inserted using C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm just concerned about Windows, so there's no need to go into esoterica about Mono compatibility or anything like that.

I should also add that the app that I'm writing is WPF, and I'd prefer to avoid taking a dependency on `System.Windows.Forms` if at all possible.

Comment: Are we talking about a USB port?

Comment: A USB drive would be an example of a removable disk, but Windows generally treats them the same as optical drives and the like when it comes to events.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Give this a shot...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace WMITestConsolApplication
{

    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            AddInsertUSBHandler();
            AddRemoveUSBHandler();
            while (true) {
            }

        }

        static ManagementEventWatcher w = null;

        static void AddRemoveUSBHandler()
        {

            WqlEventQuery q;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

            try {

                q = new WqlEventQuery();
                q.EventClassName = "__InstanceDeletionEvent";
                q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
                q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
                w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
                w.EventArrived += USBRemoved;

                w.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {


                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                if (w != null)
                {
                    w.Stop();

                }
            }

        }

        static void AddInsertUSBHandler()
        {

            WqlEventQuery q;
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
            scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

            try {

                q = new WqlEventQuery();
                q.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
                q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
                q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
                w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
                w.EventArrived += USBInserted;

                w.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {

                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                if (w != null)
                {
                    w.Stop();

                }
            }

        }

        static void USBInserted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("A USB device inserted");

        }

        static void USBRemoved(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("A USB device removed");

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What assembly is the ManagementEventWatcher in?

Comment: System.Management, according to this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx

Comment: Looks like it is in System.Management.dll - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementeventwatcher.aspx

Comment: @Josh: might I recommend that you rename the "AddInsetUSBHandler" to "AddInsertUSBHandler"?

Comment: On my system I get 4 insert and 4 remove events when I plug in, then yank out my pen drive...

Comment: On my system I get two insert events and two remove events. Can't seem to tell them apart. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

There are much less cumbersome ways of doing this than using WMI polling - just capture WM_DEVICECHANGE:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363215.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to create an Autoplay Handler:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/AutoplayDemo.aspx

> Autoplay Version 2 is a feature in
>   Windows XP that will scan the first
>   four levels of a removable media, when
>   it arrives, looking for media content
>   types (music, graphics, or video).
>   Registration of applications is done
>   on a content type basis. When a
>   removable media arrives, Windows XP
>   determines what actions to perform by
>   evaluating the content and comparing
>   it to registered handlers for that
>   content.

A [detailed MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301341.aspx) is also available.

Comment: That's pretty cool, but I'm really just looking for something that will operate while my software is running. Thanks, though.