# Can Serial Port connection triggers an Event

Tags: c#, wpf, serial-port

I have a **ComboBox** that list out available COM ports. If there are new serial ports (e.g. USB) connected to computer in run-time, I have to trigger an event (e.g. Button) to run **SerialPort.GetPortNames()** and refreshes the **ComboBoxItems**. I wonder if it's possible to auto trigger an event once a new Serial Port is connected? (I know it's impossible for RS323, but at least for USB)

Comment: To my knowledge, this is not possible. You will need to poll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How do I detect when a removable disk is inserted using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271238/how-do-i-detect-when-a-removable-disk-is-inserted-using-c)