# Getting the Drive letter of USB drive inserted

Tags: c#

I have detected the insertion of USB drive in my WPF application by following suggestions in given link [How do I detect when a removable disk is inserted using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271238/how-do-i-detect-when-a-removable-disk-is-inserted-using-c)

but I am unable to figure out the Drive letter of the detected USB drive; my Code is given below

```
    static ManagementEventWatcher w = null;
    static void AddInsertUSBHandler()
    {

        WqlEventQuery q;
        ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("root\\CIMV2");
        scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

        try {

            q = new WqlEventQuery();
            q.EventClassName = "__InstanceCreationEvent";
            q.WithinInterval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
            q.Condition = "TargetInstance ISA 'Win32_USBControllerdevice'";
            w = new ManagementEventWatcher(scope, q);
            w.EventArrived += USBInserted;

            w.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            if (w != null)
            {
                w.Stop();

            }
        }

    }

    static void USBInserted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("A USB device inserted");

    }
```

Kindly guide me if possible.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps, its code based on Neeraj Dubbey’s answer.

We run code in a continuous multithreaded loop that keeps checking for a change in connected USB devices. Because we keep track of previously connected devices we can compare it against a new list of devices. We can also determine if a device is removed using the same method.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Management;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Usb_Test
{
    class Program
    {
        private static List<USBDeviceInfo> previousDecices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Thread thread = new Thread(DeviceDetection);
            thread.Start();

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void DeviceDetection()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

                ManagementObjectCollection collection;
                using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
                    collection = searcher.Get();

                foreach (var device in collection)
                {
                    devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
                    (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID")
                    ));
                }

                if (previousDecices == null || !previousDecices.Any()) // So we don't detect already plugged in devices the first time.
                    previousDecices = devices;

                var insertionDevices = devices.Where(d => !previousDecices.Any(d2 => d2.DeviceID == d.DeviceID));
                if (insertionDevices != null && insertionDevices.Any())
                {
                    foreach(var value in insertionDevices)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Inserted: " + value.DeviceID); // Add your own event for the insertion of devices.
                    }
                }    

                var removedDevices = previousDecices.Where(d => !devices.Any(d2 => d2.DeviceID == d.DeviceID));
                if (removedDevices != null && removedDevices.Any())
                {
                    foreach (var value in removedDevices)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Removed: " + value.DeviceID); // Add your own event for the removal of devices.
                    }
                }

                previousDecices = devices;
                collection.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    class USBDeviceInfo
    {
        public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID)
        {
            this.DeviceID = deviceID;
        }
        public string DeviceID { get; private set; }

    }
}
```

However this is not a great solution, you're a lot better off listening for WM_DEVICECHANGE.

> Windows will send WM_DEVICECHANGE message to all applications whenever
>   some hardware change occurs, including when a flash drive (or other
>   removable device) is inserted or removed. The WParam parameter of this
>   message contains code which specifies exactly what event occurred. For
>   our purpose only the following events are interesting:
>
> DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL - sent after a device or piece of media has been
>   inserted. Your program will receive this message when the device is
>   ready for use, at about the time when Explorer displays the dialog
>   which lets you choose what to do with the inserted media.
>
> DBT_DEVICEQUERYREMOVE - sent when the system requests permission to
>   remove a device or piece of media. Any application can deny this
>   request and cancel the removal. This is the important event if you
>   need to perform some action on the flash drive before it is removed,
>   e.g. encrypt some files on it. Your program can deny this request
>   which will cause Windows to display the well-known message saying that
>   the device cannot be removed now.
>
> DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE - sent after a device has been removed. When
>   your program receives this event, the device is no longer available —
>   at the time when Windows display its "device has been removed" bubble
>   to the user.

Here are some links that each detail an answer on how to do this in C#:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18062/Detecting-USB-Drive-Removal-in-a-C-Program
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/60579/A-USB-Library-to-Detect-USB-Devices

Both solution should work, and you can always adapt them to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this console based code afetr adding the reference of `System.Management` in project

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Management; // need to add System.Management to your project references.

class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

    foreach (var usbDevice in usbDevices)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Device ID: {0}", usbDevice.DeviceID);

    }

    Console.Read();
}

static List<USBDeviceInfo> GetUSBDevices()
{
    List<USBDeviceInfo> devices = new List<USBDeviceInfo>();

    ManagementObjectCollection collection;
    using (var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
        collection = searcher.Get();

    foreach (var device in collection)
    {
        devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo(
        (string)device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID")
        ));
    }

    collection.Dispose();
    return devices;
}
}

class USBDeviceInfo
{
public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID)
{
    this.DeviceID = deviceID;
}
public string DeviceID { get; private set; }

}
```

Comment: The issue is this code only works for already plugged in devices and I want to pick the drive letter at the time a USB drive is plugged in